# php is unable to write to file

Tags: php, iis-7

This is on Windows Small Business Server 2011 Essentials running iis7

The following code always returns "unable to write"

```
<?php

 $myFile = "http://www.ascbits.com/test/test.txt";

 if (is_writable($myFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
 }else{
    die("unable to write");
 }

 $body = "test ";

 fwrite($fh, $body);
 fclose($fh);

?>
```

I've checked the permissions on the file and it looks like I should be able to write to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Notwithstanding your comment, you don't have the correct permissions. Remember that you need to set the permissions for the user that your web server is using.

Comment: You're trying to write to a web address?

Comment: I wonder if using a href url is the way to go. I think you need a directory path.

Comment: Change `$myFile = "http://www.ascbits.com/test/test.txt";` to just `$myFile = "test/test.txt";` if running your code from the root of your server.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$myFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/test.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP streams layer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php) is what allows you to read and write to URLs.  If you check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) on the http stream wrapper, you'll see that it's read-only:

> Allows read-only access to files/resources via HTTP 1.0, using the HTTP GET method.

It looks like you're just trying to write to a local file.  Reference it by path, depending on where it's located the following may work:

```
$myFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/test.txt";
$myFile = "test/test.txt";
```